# Save a DataFrame in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I`m trying to save my data frame in *.orc using jdbc in postgresql. I have an intermediate table created in my localhost on the server I use, but the table is not saved in postgresql.
I would like to find out what extensions postgresql works with (you may not be able to create a *.orc table in it), and that it accepts - a Dataset or sql query from the created table.
I'm using spark.

```
Properties conProperties = new Properties();
conProperties.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
conProperties.setProperty("user", srgs[2]);
conProperties.setProperty("password", args[3]);

finalTable.write()
        .format("orc")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .jdbc(args[1], "dataTable", conProperties);

spark-submit --class com.pack.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster /project/build/libs/mainC-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ha-cluster?jdbc:postgresql://MyHostame:5432/nameUser&user=nameUser&password=passwordUser
```

Comment: This question needs more information. What version of Postgres? Example code is needed. What is the intermediate table schema? What are you doing to save in Postgres?

Comment: An intermediate table is a table with all changes that appears in dbeaver(localhost). I don't know exactly the postgres version

Comment: I tried to save the converted df but it didn't work, I also tried from the table in dbeaver.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can save df in postgresql without an sql query.

Comment: The only thing I know of is https://blog.dbi-services.com/optimized-row-columnar-orc-format-in-postgresql/  Based off:https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw Not sure how that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep the `.orc` format in Postgres. You wouldn't want that either.

See updated `write` below

```
finalTable.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", srgs[1])
  .option("dbtable", "dataTable")
  .option("user", srgs[2])
  .option("password", args[3])
  .save()
```